# Computer freezes during using LibreOffice

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, freeze, gpu-driver

After latest Ubuntu 12.04 update when I using LibreOffice after some time my screen freezes and I have to reboot. I think something is wrong with video drivers. I uninstall and install new video drivers (nvidia), remove/install LibreOffice 5.1 and problem still exists. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you don't need any configuration that you have done at libreoffice, then delete the folder `/home/thanos/.config/libreoffice` (maybe some configuration causes problem after update or something). Using http://paste.ubuntu.com/ give us a link with the `~/xsession-errors` contents and a second link with  `~/xsession-errors.old` contents.

Comment: I would open a terminal and start `top` or `htop` there. then open a second terminal and launch LibreOffice from there. Keep both terminals  visible and start working. If your system hangs see if htop is still updating. In addition check if you can login to another TTY at that point - or if you can ssh in from a second machine. In many cases such systems are still accessible, which gives a good debug starting point

Comment: I had similar problems with LibreOffice also and changing graphics driver solved the problem. But I have AMD graphics. I changed Open Source driver for fglrx.

Comment: Thanos Apostolou: what do you mean "~/xsession-errors"?. I am newbie in Ubuntu. Please explain.

Comment: dufte: do you know any fglrx equivalent for nvidia?